# Using mod to replace if else statement

Tags: python, modulo

I am writing a program to generate random 12-tone scales (music theory) and store them in a list `numbers[]`

I have one function called `invert()` which takes the difference between each value and then operates that on the previous number to invert the intervals in the list.

for example, (1,5,4,7,8,3) inverted would be (1,9,10,7,6,11)

```
def invert():

    diff = [b - a for (a, b) in zip(numbers[:-1], numbers[1:])]

    for a in range(11):

        if numbers[a] - diff[a] > 11:

            numbers[a+1] = numbers[a] - diff[a] - 12

        elif numbers[a] - diff[a] < -11:

            numbers[a+1] = numbers[a] - diff[a] + 12

        else: 

            numbers[a+1] = numbers[a] - diff[a]

    return numbers
```

My question is how I would use modulo to remove the usage of these if statements.
Is there a way to use mod to wrap around numbers, so if the difference is -15 it would be revalued to -3?

Answer (score 0):

I used this part of the question "for example, (1,5,4,7,8,3) inverted would be (1,9,10,7,6,11)" as a guide.

The dectave(? ...like octave, but with 12 tones instead of 8 for a diatonic scale) may be inverted by first removing the negative values and then ensure our value does not go outside of our 12 note range.

def invert():

```
numbers = [1, 5, 4, 7, 8, 3, 2, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12]

diff = [b - a for (a, b) in zip(numbers[:-1], numbers[1:])]

for a in range(11):

        if numbers[a] - diff[a] % -12 < 12:
            numbers[a + 1] = numbers[a] - diff[a] % -12

        else:
            numbers[a + 1] = numbers[a] - diff[a] % 12

        if numbers[a] - diff[a] % 12 is 0:
            numbers[a + 1] = 12

return numbers
```

Output - [1, 9, 10, 7, 6, 11, 12, 8, 5, 4, 3, 2]